# Nextjs export timeout configuration

Tags: build, static, next.js, timeout, export

I am building a website with NextJS that takes some time to build. It has to create a big dictionary, so when I run `next dev` it takes around 2 minutes to build.

The issue is, when I run `next export` to get a static version of the website there is a timeout problem, because the build takes (as I said before), 2 minutes, whihc exceeds the 60 seconds limit pre-configured in next.

In the NEXT documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-page-generation-timeout it explains that you can increase the timeout limit, whose default is 60 seconds: "Increase the timeout by changing the staticPageGenerationTimeout configuration option (default 60 in seconds)."

However it does not specify WHERE you can set that configuration option. In next.config.json? in package.json?

I could not find this information anywhere, and my blind tries of putting this parameter in some of the files mentioned before did not work out at all. So,  **Does anybody know how to set the timeout of next export?** Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like it goes in [next.config.json](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/809d0155ffc98250d84ef2ddfbc729a13a551287/packages/next/server/config-shared.ts#L125). Did it not work for you? What error did you face?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Changed the time to 500 seconds but still getting the error.

Comment: Hi, I tried again with putting the following code in next.config.js:  `module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  @type {import('next').NextConfig}
   
  const nextConfig = {
   staticPageGenerationTimeout: 2000
    /* config options here */
  }
  return nextConfig
}`                                                                                          According to the documentation. But it doesn't work still

Comment: What version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: I am using Next.js v12.0.4 . However I found out Next doesn't like that i am using html <img> tags instead of the <Image> inbuilt in NextJS. I don't know if this is the problem, I will be solving it soon and seeing if that was the issue all along

Comment: What data does it collect, can we turn it off ?

Comment: Hi, Yes, it is solved now :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They were a bit more clear in the [basic-features/data-fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) part of the docs that it should be placed in the `next.config.js`

I added this to mine and it worked (got rid of the `Error: Collecting page data for /path/[pk] is still timing out after 2 attempts. See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-data-collection-timeout` build error):

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  // time in seconds of no pages generating during static
  // generation before timing out
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1000,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are using `<img/>` html tag instead of next image component , i had same problem and solving with replace that